# Make div stick to the bottom regardless of height of parent

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a shopping cart, where the items are listed (green), and a "suggestion box" (pink) should be displayed on the bottom.

The suggestion box (pink) should stay on the bottom always; when items are getting added to the list (green), it should not cover them up, but move to the bottom of the list.

Basically, it should stay on the end of the list, and if there is only one or no items(green) on the list, Suggestion box(pink) should stay on the bottom.

Any idea on what do I need to set here?

Honestly, I have no clue on what I am doing, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here's my demo: https://codepen.io/ycckgmlm-the-sans/pen/mdjxEeV

```css
#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  bottom: 0px;
  color: #000433;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: fixed;
  right: 50px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 450px;
}

#scroller {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#list-wrapper {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#green {
  height: 250px;
  width: 410px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 20px;
}

#pink {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  bottom: 0;
  position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="scroller">
    <div id="list-wrapper">
      <div id="green">Item should scroll</div>
      <!--
          <div id="green">Item should scroll</div>
          <div id="green">Item should scroll</div>
          <div id="green">Item should scroll</div>
          -->
      <div id="pink">Pink<br>Stays on bottom and not covering up items on the list.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you amenable to a slight adjustment of your HTML? It's easier - [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/skta0m14/) - if the `.green` items are in a separate wrapper to the `.pink` item.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change   `position: sticky;`  to  `position: absolute;` of `#pink`

Comment: If I do this, then if more Greens added, the Pink will cover them up.

Answer (score 0):

I changed 3 things:

- Switch sticky for absolute on pink element.
- Add margin-bottom to green to leave space for pink element.
- I set the wrapper to position relative, so pink element uses bottom of this wrapper

```css
#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  bottom: 0px;
  color: #000433;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: fixed;
  right: 50px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 450px;
}

#scroller {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#list-wrapper {
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 250px;
}

#green {
  height: 250px;
  width: 410px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 20px;

}

#pink {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="scroller">
    <div id="list-wrapper">
      <div id="green">Item should scroll</div>
          <div id="green">Item should scroll</div>
          <div id="green">Item should scroll</div>
          <div id="green">Item should scroll</div>
      <div id="pink">Pink<br>Stays on bottom and not covering up items on the list.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this as well, but when there is only 1 or no green, then pink needs to stay on the bottom and not to move to the top.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **flex** to solve the problem.

*This is the **updated** answer:*

change your CSS for **list-wrapper**, **green** and **pink** to this:

```css
#list-wrapper {
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: end;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#green {
  height: 250px;
  width: 410px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 20px;
  justify-self: start;
}
#pink {
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
    justify-self: end;
}
```

Comment: Something is not good with this. I have tried this, but it does not work, and pink does not stay on the bottom.

Comment: @Tibby mmm.... I just tried it on the codepen link you shared and it works. If you're working on it on a project that includes more codes and styling, please check if any other stylings are affecting it or not.  And please let me know about your findings.

Comment: Hmm... can you please share it on Jsfiddle or an updated version of codepen?

Comment: @Tibby sure, here you are: https://codepen.io/Chitgar/pen/ExpEgZK

Comment: Thank you! 
So the problem is, when you take the greens off or just leave one, then pink will not stick to the bottom. It will go up. Somehow I want the pink to stick to the bottom if there are no greens. I might should try Jquery to somehow check if overflow is scroll? if not then just position:absolute, bottom: 0 ?

Comment: @Tibby I see. I made some changes https://codepen.io/Chitgar/pen/ExpEgZK .
The background colors are to see what's happening.